# MySql Query is not returning the correct result when I try to query between Dates

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $this->db->query("SELECT skip_date, date_type
        FROM qte_shipping_date_skip 
        WHERE (date_type = 5 OR date_type = 2)
        AND (skip_date > '2019-18-01 00:00:00 ')
        ORDER BY skip_date ASC;");
```

Here is what I am getting back on on php page.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [skip_date] => 5/25/2015 [date_type] => 5 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [skip_date] => 5/25/2020 [date_type] => 5 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [skip_date] => 5/26/2014 [date_type] => 5 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [skip_date] => 5/27/2013 [date_type] => 2 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [skip_date] => 5/27/2019 [date_type] => 5 ) [5] => stdClass Object
```

I can't get the correct results back. The result I expect to see are dates above 2019 however I see dates that are from before 2019. What can I be doing wrong?

I have tried the following query to see to make sure they are the same date format. Still nothing.

```
        FROM qte_shipping_date_skip 
        WHERE (date_type = 5 OR date_type = 2)
        AND (dboSTR_TO_DATE(skip_date, '%m-%d-%Y') > STR_TO_DATE('07-09-2018', '%m-%d-%Y'))
        ORDER BY skip_date ASC;");
```

Comment: What is the column type of the `skip_date` column? Is it Date, or varchar?

Comment: Make sure the column you're storing dates in is a proper `datetime` field and only store dates in `Y-m-d H:i:s` (which is the date MySQL uses). Use the same format when querying the data. `2019-18-01 00:00:00` must to be `Y-d-m H:i:s` (which is wrong)

Comment: @ADyson Great question! I have determined that skip_date is actualy  varchar.

Comment: @zootechdrum the best next then is to fix it!

Comment: You should always store dates in a Date column, that's what it's for. Then any comparisons you do on it (such as filtering or sorting) are done as dates, not strings. then you should fix the date format in your query as well, and you should be fine.

Comment: You are correct @ADyson . Thankfully we were able to change it without to much issue. I am working with a really old database . As you an imagine things have started to depend on that column being a string instead of the proper date format.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, your query would be more usually written as:

```
SELECT skip_date
     , date_type
  FROM qte_shipping_date_skip
 WHERE date_type IN(2,5)
   AND skip_date > '2019-18-01 00:00:00'
 ORDER 
    BY skip_date;
```